# How do I read parquet with Spark that has unsupported types?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to use PySpark to pull data from a parquet file that contains `UINT64` columns which currently maps to `typeNotSupported()` in [Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/75cf369c742e7c7b68f384d123447c97be95c9f0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetSchemaConverter.scala#L99). I do not need these columns, so I was hoping I could pull the other columns using predicate pushdown with the following command:

```
spark.read.parquet('path/to/dir/').select('legalcol1', 'legalcol2')
```

However, I was still met with the following error.

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o86.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, 
most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, ..., executor 1):
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Parquet type not supported: INT64 (UINT_64);
```

Is there a way to ingest this data without throwing the above error?

Comment: which version of spark you are using ?

Comment: I am using version 2.4.3

Comment: AFAIK with spark its not possible. May be you have to use parquet tools for these convertions ?

Answer (score -4):

You can try to convert any column type into another column type:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet('path/to/dir/')

df.select(col('legalcol1').cast('string').alias('col1'), col('legalcol2').cast('string').alias('col2'))
```

Convert to bigint column type:

```
df.select(col('uint64col').cast('bigint').alias('bigint_col'))
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: You can make any adjustment belong to that matter, and doing proper type casting as the sample above.

Comment: @jo0gbe4bstjb it's not an answer because the like for the `read` throws the exception.